# Shifting a Binary String to the right in machine code/assembly language

Tags: assembly, lc3

I understand that doing 15 shifts to the left would shift a binary sequence to the right by one. However after setting the initial register values, if register 1 is equal to 1; the programs gives the correct solution. Anything larger stored in register 1 causes the program to give the wrong solutions. I'm Working with the LC-3; here is my bin file code:

```
0011000000000000        ; Orig
0010000011111111        ; R0 <- mem[x3100]
0010001011111111        ; R1 <- mem[x3101]
0101010010100000        ; R2 <- R2 AND #0
0001001001100000        ; R1 <- R1 + #0
0000010000001101        ; BRz R1
0001010010101111        ; R2 <- R2+15
0000010000001001        ; BRz R2
0001000000100000        ; R0 = R0 + #0
0000100000000011        ; BRn
0001000000000000        ; R0 <- R0+R0
0001010010111111        ; R2--
0000111111111010        ; BRnzp PCOffset
0001000000000000        ; R0 <- R0 + R0
0001000000000001        ; R0 <- R0 + #1
0001010010111111        ; R2--
0000111 111110110       ; BRnzp PCOffset
0001001001111111        ; R1--
0000 111 111110001      ; BRnzp PCOffset
0011 000 011101111      ; St R0 -> mem[x3102]
1111000000100101        ; Halt
```

Comment: Rotating does that, shifting discards bits. As for your code, single step it and see where exactly it goes wrong, don't just check the end result.

Comment: I'm a little confused what you're using R1 for in your example. I'm guessing R2 is your counter and R0 is supposed to house the solution, but what's R1 used for? In your code you check R1 to make sure it has a value, but if it has anything other than 1 it will loop most of your program all over again until R1 is decreased to 0.

Comment: R0 is my number in binary to be shifted/rotated, R1 is the amount of shift and rotates ro the right, R2 is the counter to shift/rotate 15 times

Answer (score 4):

Found the line of code that's giving you trouble

```
0001000000000001        ; R0 <- R0 + #1
```

this isn't adding 1 to R0 it's actually adding R1 to R0.

```
0001000000000001        ; R0 <- R0 + R1
```

---

What you need to replace that line with is:

```
0001000000100001        ; R0 <- R0 + #1
```

You're missing the add immediate bit [5].